# I am wondering how to make a storm trooper helmet in blender

Tags: modeling

I am fairly new to blender, and I am wondering how to make a storm trooper helmet. There are no tutorials out there, and I was just wondering if anyone knew how. Thanks

Comment: You could use an image of front and side view and set this as background image in the viewport, after that you would extrude edges along the contours, excellent exercise.

Comment: Any tutorial on head modelling that uses reference images can easily adapt to a helmet.

Comment: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/animation-and-3d/9780470102602/working-with-meshes/extrusion_modeling_and_box_modeling

Comment: Also, look for tutorials on hard surface objects. They will probably come in handy.